# pH code of Arduino SEN0169 refuses to output

Tags: software

Good day everyone!

I'm making my research project a hydroponics sensor that collects air and water temperature, humidity, conductivity, and pH, then sends it through a sim900a GSM module. However, when testing it out, the pH part of the code does not work. When I removed the part of the code that collects pH, the device worked as intended. I got the code from the manufacturer's website, but I'm not sure what to change to make it work. Thank you very much!

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <GravityTDS.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5
#define DHTPIN 7     
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define TdsSensorPin A1

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);
GravityTDS gravityTds;

#define SensorPin A0            //pH meter Analog output to Arduino Analog Input 0
#define Offset 0.00            //deviation compensate
#define LED 13
#define samplingInterval 20
#define printInterval 800
#define ArrayLenth  40    //times of collection
int pHArray[ArrayLenth];   //Store the average value of the sensor feedback
int pHArrayIndex=0;

char msg;
char call;

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  Serial.println("GSM SIM900A BEGIN");
  Serial.println("Enter character for control option:");
  Serial.println("h : to disconnect a call");
  Serial.println("i : to receive a call");
  Serial.println("s : to send information");
  Serial.println("c : to make a call");  
  Serial.println("e : to redial");
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
  
  dht.begin();
  
  sensors.begin();
  
  gravityTds.setPin(A1);
  gravityTds.setAref(5.0);
  gravityTds.setAdcRange(1024);
  gravityTds.begin();
  
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{  

  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'c':
      MakeCall();
      break;
    case 'h':
      HangupCall();
      break;
    case 'e':
      RedialCall();
      break;
    case 'i':
      ReceiveCall();
      break;
  }
 if (mySerial.available()>0)
 Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}

void SendMessage()
{
  
  int h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float tdsValue = 0;
  float temperature = t;
  gravityTds.setTemperature(temperature);  
  gravityTds.update(); 
  tdsValue = gravityTds.getTdsValue();  
    
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 

  
  
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+639494145111\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  mySerial.print(h);// The SMS text you want to send
  mySerial.print("% humidity, ");
  mySerial.print(t);
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius air temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius water temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(tdsValue,0);
  mySerial.println(" ppm, ");

  static unsigned long samplingTime = millis();
  static unsigned long printTime = millis();
  static float pHValue,voltage;
  if(millis()-samplingTime > samplingInterval)
  {
      pHArray[pHArrayIndex++]=analogRead(SensorPin);
      if(pHArrayIndex==ArrayLenth)pHArrayIndex=0;
      voltage = avergearray(pHArray, ArrayLenth)*5.0/1024;
      pHValue = 3.5*voltage+Offset;
      samplingTime=millis();
  }
  if(millis() - printTime > printInterval)   //Every 800 milliseconds, print a numerical, convert the state of the LED indicator
  {
    mySerial.print(pHValue,2);
    mySerial.print(" pH value");
        digitalWrite(LED,digitalRead(LED)^1);
        printTime=millis();
  }
}
double avergearray(int* arr, int number){
  int i;
  int max,min;
  double avg;
  long amount=0;
  if(number<=0){
    Serial.println("Error number for the array to avraging!/n");
    return 0;
  }
  if(number<5){   //less than 5, calculated directly statistics
    for(i=0;i<number;i++){
      amount+=arr[i];
    }
    avg = amount/number;
    return avg;
  }else{
    if(arr[0]<arr[1]){
      min = arr[0];max=arr[1];
    }
    else{
      min=arr[1];max=arr[0];
    }
    for(i=2;i<number;i++){
      if(arr[i]<min){
        amount+=min;        //arr<min
        min=arr[i];
      }else {
        if(arr[i]>max){
          amount+=max;    //arr>max
          max=arr[i];
        }else{
          amount+=arr[i]; //min<=arr<=max
        }
      }//if
    }//for
    avg = (double)amount/(number-2);
  }//if
  return avg;
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}

void ReceiveMessage()
{
  mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); // AT Command to recieve a live SMS
  delay(1000);
  if (mySerial.available()>0)
  {
    msg=mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(msg);
  }
}

void MakeCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATD+639494145111;"); // ATDxxxxxxxxxx; -- watch out here for semicolon at the end!!
  Serial.println("Calling  "); // print response over serial port
  delay(1000);
}


void HangupCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATH");
  Serial.println("Hangup Call");
  delay(1000);
}

void ReceiveCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATA");
  delay(1000);
  {
    call=mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(call);
  }
}

void RedialCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATDL");
  Serial.println("Redialing");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: start by running only the pH code ... remove everything else ... if the pH code does not run on its own, then it won't run as a part of a larger program either

Comment: The pH program works on its own, so it's only when I incorporate it like this that the pH value doesn't output

Comment: how do you know that the pH part of the program does not work? ... you have no debugging code that prints information to Serial

Comment: I used just the pH code in another sketch and it outputs the pH there.

Comment: that means nothing really ... it could just as easily be the GSM code ... you don't know if that part of code even runs